# IXmlSerializable Raise Event UnknownElement in XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, events, xml-serialization

Is it possible to raise events to [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swxzdhc0.aspx) on a class that implements [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx)?

I am implementing on my [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swxzdhc0.aspx) classes, however, I would like raise an event such as [Unknown Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a51hxdw.aspx) or [Unknown Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a51hxdw.aspx).

I have considered throwing an exception but I would rather raise an event rather than halt my deserialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML Serializer does not support events.